# Asp.Net Core Cache Tag Helper

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, .net-core

I am trying to cache the top navigation bar which contains pinned dashboards and user profile image, I am using Cache tag helper to cache the top navigation bar, but when a user change the pinned dashboards or his profile image I want to invalidate the cache to load the new profile image.

```
    <cache vary-by="@userService.ProfileChanged">
    <header class="header">
    <nav class="navbar fixed-top navbar-light bg-light d-flex justify-content-between">
        <ul class="main-nav-icons list-unstyled d-flex flex-fill mr-3">
            <cache vary-by="@userService.PinnedDashboardsChanged">
                @await Component.InvokeAsync("UserDashboards", new { type = "pinned" })
            </cache>
            <li><button class="btn btn-unstyled left-nav-toggler"><i class="glyphicons glyphicons-option-horizontal text-primary1"></i></button></li>
        </ul>
        <cache vary-by="@userService.ProfileChanged">
            <ul class="d-flex justify-content-end align-items-center user-menu mb-0 flex-fill list-unstyled">
                <li>
                    <ul class="user-menu-details d-flex mr-2 list-unstyled mb-0 flex-column flex-md-row">
                        <li class="list-inline-item">@(userService.User.UserTypeId == 1 ? "Dios Kernel" : userService.User.Environment.Name)</li>
                        <li class="list-inline-item"> <a href="@Url.Action("Index", "Profile")">@userService.User.FullName</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li class="list-inline-item user-avatar">
                    <div class="dropdown">

                        <a class="dropdown-toggle avatar-img" data-toggle="dropdown" style="background-image:url('@(string.IsNullOrEmpty(userService.User.ProfilePhoto) ? "/images/user-pic.png" : userService.User.ProfilePhoto)')">
                            @*<img src="@(string.IsNullOrEmpty(userService.User.ProfilePhoto) ? "/images/user-pic.png" : userService.User.ProfilePhoto)" alt="@userService.User.FullName">*@
                        </a>

                        <div class="dropdown-menu">
                            <a class="dropdown-item" onclick="editProfile('@Url.Action("_Edit","Profile")')">
                                <i class="fas fa-user-alt"></i>
                                Edit Profile
                            </a>
                            <a class="dropdown-item" onclick="resetPassword('@Url.Action("_ResetPassword","Account")')">
                                <i class="fas fa-lock"></i>
                                Change Password
                            </a>
                            <a class="dropdown-item" href="@Url.Action("Logout","Account")">
                                <i class="fas fa-sign-out-alt"></i>
                                Logout
                            </a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </cache>
    </nav>
</header>
</cache>
```

I have used vary-by and used ProfileChanged property which I change true when the user update the profile, But when I am facing a strange behavior which is the first refresh on any page show the new change but the other do not, I expect that the first request after the change will recache the navigation again for any other pages.

Comment: if `ProfileChanged` is a `bool` it will default back to `false` right after changing which will bring the cached result when it was `false`. You should try to store last update time and vary it by date.

Comment: default back to false by the framework? actually I call it one time only in a request and I change it to false once it called with the true value.
I think ProfileChanged should be a timestamp and I change it once the user updates the profile

Comment: what I understand is the caching happens at the server which means if one request updates the cached version then all requests should get the new cached version whatever the value of ProfileChanged

Comment: when `ProfileChanged` = `false` it shows `A`, when `ProfileChanged` = `true` it shows `B`. I asked you if it was a bool so we can confirm that after the `ProfileChanged` changes back to `false`, since after you refresh the page it is no longer in the state of being updated. The cache happens on the server, but think of the value as a pointer to the address where the cache result is stored, so yes use a timestamp so the pointer is always different.

Comment: I think you are right, but I mean if the server caches a component view then if any page contains this component refreshes it at the server then why the other pages get the old state of the component

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are getting confused with the work flow, so consider taking this step by step.

In this example I made a simple .net core project, where the razor page accepts 2 parameters an `int a` and `bool b` in the route query.

In the razor view I would have the following:

```
<cache vary-by="@a">
    Time at @a @DateTime.Now;
</cache>
<br />
<cache vary-by="@b">
    Time at @b @DateTime.Now;
</cache>
```

Now let's step through some results

1. 1st Request, Query: `?a=1&b=true`
   Time at 1 **01/10/2018 19:31:11**; 
   Time at True **01/10/2018 19:31:11**;
2. 2nd Request, Query: `?a=2&b=true`
   Time at 2 **01/10/2018 19:31:20**; 
   Time at True **01/10/2018 19:31:11**;
3. 3rd Request, Query: `?a=2&b=false`
   Time at 2 **01/10/2018 19:31:20**; 
   Time at False **01/10/2018 19:31:32**;
4. 4th Request, Query: `?a=1&b=false`
   Time at 1 **01/10/2018 19:31:11**; 
   Time at False **01/10/2018 19:31:32**;

Now to solve your problem. You have to set the `ProfileChanged` value to a time stamp, otherwise if you are not saving it to the database when the default value of `ProfileChanged` is set back to `false` after the refresh you will be left with the previously cached result for the key `false` **which is stored for 20 min by default**.

Comment: Thank you very much, I have understood how it works, I thought it caches one version only and refresh it once the state of the value in vary-by changed regardless it's value